# Changing SSD drive what can I do with the old SSD

Tags: ssd

I currently have a 500GB SSD drive as my C drive which is nearly full and will be replacing it with a 1TB SSD. I'll be cloning the old drive but wondered how I can use the old SSD which is perfectly fine. Can I simply hook it up and reformat it? Any info would be appreciated.

Comment: Once you're sure the data is safe and transfered properly, run DBAN http://www.dban.org/download on the SSD and then just connect it up and you can use it as an additional drive.

Comment: @David why wouldnt he just reformat with os support? Sounds a lot easier..

Comment: @MattiasÅslund Not as secure and also not as thorough. OS reformat will not always do a perfect job. There is after all a reason these 3rd party programs exist....

Comment: Self-encrypting drives, which a 500gb probably is, only requires resetting the encryption key to do a secure erase.

Answer (score 2):

After cloning your drive, you can reformat it and use it as an additional drive as long as your motherboard has enough sata ports (which it probably has). Also keep in mind that bigger SSDs are faster.

BTW, Don't forget to change which drive you are booting from, like @Journeyman Geek♦ mentioned.

Formatting the SSD normally is fine as long as you don't have sensitive data that you don't want others to recover.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much. I'd make sure you're booting off the new drive (by picking the drive from the bios/uefi boot menu), and reformat the old drive from there. If you're going to use the disk for yourself, that's about it.

Else you may want to run a SSD specific secure erase tool, since old school wiping techniques may not work. Not sure what would let you run the 'sata secure erase' command except maybe hdparm though.

Answer (score 1):

> what can I do with the old SSD

- Keep in in the same computer as a secondary drive, or
- Put it in a seconc computer which still has spinning rust.
- Give it to a family member who still uses spinning rust.
- Use it as an external backupdrive
- Use it as a backup copy (aka keep all data on it and put it in a drawer).
- Use it as a doorstop.
- Sell it on ebay

...
So many thing you can do with it, But without more ideas about your goals it is a too broad question.